# Is is possible to package a .app for OS X?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've read about [Packaged Apps](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/about_apps.html) and played with the example apps. I can load them into my Chrome Canary, but I can't seem to find a way to build/package a .app for OS X. Is this not possible yet, or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Previously Google Chrome packaged apps were only for Google Chrome. According to a [recent blog post](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/02/chrome-app-launcher-developer-preview.html) by Sriram Saroop, the product manager for Chromium, there is an available Chrome App Launcher to run Google Chrome packaged apps outside of the browser.

[image]

The Chrome App Launcher will be coming "soon" to Mac and Linux.

Comment: Do you know if there are plans to allow this? I thought this was the point of packaged apps, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I don't know if there are plans to allow this but it could be done. I don't think building a Mac OS X .app was the point of Google Chrome packaged apps. I think packaged apps were built with Chrome OS in mind.

Comment: Chrome Packaged Apps will be executable from outside Chrome on platforms other than ChromeOS, including MacOSX. The implementation is a work in progress now, but you can get a rough idea of where it is going (in Windows, currently) by reading this post: http://blog.chromium.org/2013/02/chrome-app-launcher-developer-preview.html